# I received the error on multiple attempts. Archive Validation failed with errors

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I got Xcode to archive my latest build . I tell Organizer to "Validate..." in preparation for an upload to iTunes Connect. After a good deal of doing its thing, it finally spits this at me:

An error occurred.
The operation couldn’t be completed. (ITunesSoftwareServiceAuthenticationErrorDomain error 434.)
and 
iTunes Store operation failed.
This action could not be completed. Try again.

I received the error on multiple attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it could be a bug from xcode. You can try alternatively instead of `Validate` try to `Export your IPA for App store distribution`.By this way hope you can get IPA file of your app without any problems. Using application loader you can upload your IPA to iTunes connect.

> Open latest release Xcode version. Not Beta version xcode.

Go to Xcode menu -> Open developer tool - > Application Loader.

Comment: Im doing As  you suggest that but error is binary code are coming in sdk